# Find coordinate mapping of $V =F^2,B= \langle e_1,e_1+e_2\rangle$ Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

> Describe the coordinate mappings for the given bases on the given
> vector spaces B
>
> $V =F^2,B= \langle e_1,e_1+e_2\rangle$ and
>
> $V = P_{\le n}(F), B = \langle 1,x,2x^2,\ldots,nx^n\rangle$

I don't know what the question is actually asking. What does it mean to be a coordinate map?

Comment: Note that proper notation is $\langle e_1,e_1+e_1\rangle,$ not $<e_1,e_1+e_2>. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy oh yes. i'm still having trouble with these commands.

Comment: Google "latex symbols" and you'll see them.

Answer (score 1):

A coordinate map is an identification between linear combinations and scalar vectors with respect to an ordered basis. E.g. $2e_1 + e_2 - e_4 \leftrightarrow (2,1,0,-1)$.

Lets see what happens in the first case. Assume that $F^2 = \langle e_1, e_2\rangle$. Then you have $B = \langle e_1, e_1 + e_2\rangle$. You are asked for a map that satisfies $e_1 \mapsto e_1$, $e_1 + e_2 \mapsto e_2$. This map is simply a $2\times 2$ matrix that satisfies those two conditions. Deduce that the matrix is 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$